# Решение задачки

Tags: python, алгоритм, олимпиада

Возникла проблема при решении задачи на Python3.
Текст задачи

> Ваня принес на кухню рулет, который он хочет разделить с коллегами.
> Для этого он хочет разрезать рулет на `N` равных частей. Разумеется,
> рулет можно резать только поперек. Соотвественно, Костя сделает `N - 1` разрез ножом через равные промежутки.

> По возвращению с кофе-брейка Ваня задумался — а можно ли было обойтись
> меньшим числом движений, будь нож Вани бесконечно длинным (иначе
> говоря, если он мог бы сделать сколько угодно разрезов за раз, если
> эти разрезы лежат на одной прямой)? Считается, что места для разрезов
> намечены заранее, и все разрезы делаются с ювелирной точностью.
>
> Оказывается, что можно. Например, если Ваня хотел бы разделить рулет
> на четыре части, он мог бы обойтись двумя разрезами — сначала он
> разделил бы рулет на две половинки, а потом совместил бы две половинки
> и разрезал обе пополам одновременно.
>
> Вам дано число `N`, требуется сказать, каким минимальным числом
> разрезов можно обойтись.
>
> Формат входных данных
>
> Дано одно натуральное число `N (1≤N≤2000000000)` — количество людей на кофе-брейке.

> Формат выходных данных
>
> Выведите одно число — минимальное число движений, которое придется
> сделать Косте.

> Замечание
>
> Чтобы разрезать рулет на `6` частей, Ване сначала придется разрезать
> его на две равные части, после чего совместить две половинки и сделать
> два разреза.
>
> Чтобы разрезать рулет на `5` частей, Ване понадобится разделить его в
> соотношении `2:3`, после чего совместить два рулета по левому краю
> и разрезать больший рулет на одинарные кусочки — меньший тоже
> разделится на одинарные."

Решил ее я так:

```
a = int(input())
b = 2
c = 1
while (b<=a):
    c+=1
    b=2**c
if a-b!=0 and a-b>0:
    c+=1
print(c)
```

Проверяющая программа пишет что решение частичное, но почему я понять не могу. Только изучаю питон и буду благодарен за подсказку или совет где искать ошибку.

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Comment: Добавьте словестное описание вашего решения.

Comment: подправил задание

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша программа ошибается для небольших *N*:

> ```
> N     ваш   должно
>      ответ   быть
>
> 1      1      0          # ошибка
> 2      2      1          # ошибка
> 3      2      2
> 4      3      2          # ошибка
> 5      3      3
> 6      3      3
> 7      3      3
> 8      4      3          # ошибка
> ```

Пусть *f<sub>N</sub>* - минимальное число разрезаний для *N* кусков. Какие у него есть свойства?

1. *f<sub>1</sub> = 0* - ничего резать не надо если вы завтракаете в одиночестве.
2. *f<sub>2N</sub> ≤ 1 + f<sub>N</sub>* - если число разрезов чётное, то режем рулет строго пополам, две половинки кладём рядом и следуем решению для *N* разрезов.
3. *f<sub>N</sub> > k*, если *N > 2<sup>k</sup>*. Каждый разрез в лучшем случае удваивает число кусков. Лучший результат для *k* разрезов - *2<sup>k</sup>* кусков. Если требуется больше кусков, нужно и больше разрезов.
4. *f<sub>N+1</sub> ≥ f<sub>N</sub>* - неубывание. Разрезание для большего числа кусков годится и для меньшего числа кусков.

Из 1, 2 получается ответ для степеней двойки (*N = 2<sup>k</sup>*): по индукции *f<sub>2<sup>k</sup></sub> ≤ k*. Способ разрезания - *k* раз режем все куски пополам: *f<sub>2<sup>k</sup></sub> = k*.

Если *N* между соседними степенями двойки (*2<sup>k-1</sup> < N < 2<sup>k</sup>*), то из монотонности следует *k-1 ≤ f<sub>N</sub> ≤ k*. Из третьего пункта *k-1 < f<sub>N</sub>*. Следовательно *f<sub>N</sub> = k*.

В итоге нам надо найти `ceil(log_2(N))`:

```
n = int(input())

e = 0
p = 1
while p < n:
    e += 1
    p *= 2
print(e)
```

**P.S.** В Питоне задачу можно решить в виде замкнутой формулы. `n.bit_length()` возвращает длину числа в битах. Это почти то что нам нужно - формула ошибается на единицу на точных степенях двойки, для остальных чисел ответ верный. Проверить что число точная степень двойки можно так: `n & (n - 1) == 0`. Операция `n & (n - 1)` стирает младший ненулевой бит числа. Если число "стёрлось" до нуля, значит единичный бит в нем был только один, значит это была степень двойки.

Программа:

```
n = int(input())
print(n.bit_length() - (n & (n - 1) == 0))
```

**P.P.S.** Битовые хитрости не нужны. Предыдущее выражение просто-напросто равно `(n - 1).bit_length()`:

```
print((int(input()) - 1).bit_length())
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!  Нужно было просто строгое сравнение вместо нестрогого и один if добавить.

Comment: а можно так же элегантно,но на джаве?

Comment: @MadR, да можно: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitLength().

Answer (score 0):

Либо так через логарифм по основанию 2:

```
import math

print(math.ceil(math.log2(int(input())))
```